# IP Whitelisting in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I am confused between two Source Control System providers i.e. BitBucket and Azure DevOps. The reason behind is that BitBucket is providing IP Whitelisting feature in its Premium plan to restrict developers from accessing Projects from outside of organisation network. So my question is, can we achieve this functionality in Azure DevOps also? If yes, then how much it will cost?

Below is the link to the Pricing list of BitBucket:

https://bitbucket.org/product/pricing?tab=cloud&&aceid=&adposition=1t1&adgroup=55499719676&campaign=1407242867&creative=356084117971&device=c&keyword=bitbucket%20pricing&matchtype=e&network=g&placement=&ds_kids=p33211121374&ds_e=GOOGLE&ds_eid=700000001551985&ds_e1=GOOGLE&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI3oblooTi5AIV0oBwCh1TEQjdEAAYASAAEgKQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid that the IP Whitelisting is not supported in Azure DevOps at present. Azure DevOps usually use permission to prevent accounts to access Git repo. And I think, the IP Whitelisting is a good feature for Azure DevOps.

There have been a suggestion ticket that mentioned this feature, it will be more safe if Azure DevOps enable to set IP address only for accessing Git repos. You can vote on this ticket and post your comment, Microsoft will periodically review these feature requests and you can follow this suggestion ticket for updates.

Here is the suggestion ticket link:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/684529/enable-to-set-ip-addresses-only-for-accessing-git.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can't limit access to your Azure Repos based on ip adress.
You are however able to connect Azure DevOps to an Azure AD instance [1], this will allow you to limit access to the whole of your DevOps organization to people only in your Azure AD (which can be a local AD synced with azure [2]). There are no additional cost for this apart from the per-user license fee you already pay for people using Azure DevOps. If you are not yet using Azure AD you might run into some additional fees if you opt to use the premium AD functionality [3], but you should be able to set this up with the free variant as well.

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=azure-devops

[2] https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2014/05/13/step-by-step-syncing-an-on-premise-ad-with-azure-active-directory/

[3] https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/